# Why does the DIV tag render differently in IE8 and Firefox?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, rendering, markup

Why do div tags render differently in IE8 and Firefox?

Is there a way to have them rendered the same?

This is a very general question, the reason I ask is I am fighting both browsers when using div tags, some elements are not rendering the same.

Comment: Welcome to the internet, where different browsers are notorious for rendering things differently.

Comment: Well maybe an example would help, that's too general. Give us some code of what you are trying to do then maybe advice can be offered

Comment: TheTXI, i believe the correct vernacular is "teh interwebs"

Comment: Why was this down-voted? Seems like a legitimate question.

Comment: i thought it was the 'Enter Web', with confusion of the Enter key and spider webs.

Comment: +1 to cancel out the -1 from someone else. This seems like a legit question.

Comment: @William Brendel: People who pity vote like you are the reason people like Blankman and Sasha exist.

Comment: Div tags, or elements, render pretty much exactly the same in every browser I know. Until you add some CSS, that is...

Comment: +1 this is a very basic but legit question, don't vote down because you are an HTML ninja.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may benefit from starting off with a reset.css. This generally fixes any differences between multiple browsers. I suggest Meyer's (online at http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Simply download that .css file, and reference it first before any other css rules/files. This assumes that your problem is with the actual browsers, and not with your markup.

Comment: I hope it works. We've all been there. It's very frustrating having to deal with all the different issues between IE and FF (not to mention the others).

Comment: If your problems persist, try to skinny-down your page to just the offending markup, and then post it here. Won't take very long for us to weed out the problems together.